# How to write an RPG in Objective-C/cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i would like to know some general things when it comes to writing a RPG. I have read the following article: [RPG](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2259.asp) but the program is written in python and it only gives some ideas to what you can have inside your RPG.

What i want is to know what classes to use. like NSView vs CALayer and so on...

I want it to be in 2D =)

Comment: Honestly, start somewhere else than by tackling the whole RPG first. Do some Cocoa tutorials, or get a good book. Lots of Getting Started with Cocoa questions here on SO. Once you know how views and layers work, then worry about putting a game together.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard good things about [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).

It's a framework for 2d games, I think an RPG would work fine on it.

Comment: I've heard of cocos2d =) i actually wanted to try to program it without third party libraries, but i might try this one out ;)

Comment: I've thought about doing a game using only basic Cocoa-Touch before, but upon evaluation it seemed harder than using a built-for-games framework. Things like collision detection are looking up to be a big pain without framework help, so I didn't proceed with it. Hehe. :P